# Create a draggable Svg group

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, svg

I am using the jquery svg plugin (http://keith-wood.name/svg.html) to programmatically create svg shapes. Dragging seems to work ok for rectangles but when dealing with grouped objects (I have an object that represents a button) or when dealing with text dragging is flaky. The objects move but not where they should (they jump to different areas in the svg drawing areas).

Here is some sample code:

```
function makeDraggable(svgComponent) {
var svg = $('#svgscreen').svg('get');


$('#' + svgComponent.name, svg.root()).draggable().bind('drag', function(event, ui)  
     {
    event.target.setAttribute('x', ui.position.left);
    event.target.setAttribute('y', ui.position.top);
});


}
```

If anyone ever had to deal with something like this I would appreciate any suggestions. The component name is the unique id of the svg shape (or group in the case of grouped objects)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the objects-are-not-where-they-should-be issue. I fixed it by putting the following code in my 'drag' function:

```
// Setup (this code is actually outside of my 'drag' function, but it doesn't matter
// Replace svg-id with whatever custom id='' you have on your <svg> tag
var canvas = document.getElementById("svg-id");
var SVGMatrix = canvas.getScreenCTM().inverse();
var point = canvas.createSVGPoint();

// Convert html coordinates to SVG coordinates
point.x = event.pageX;
point.y = event.pageY;
point = point.matrixTransform(SVGMatrix);

// Update coordinates manually, since SVG uses its own attributes
event.target.setAttribute('cx', point.x);
event.target.setAttribute('cy', point.y);
```